# QGIS Options CRS setting error that cannot be changed

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3

At some point, maybe after a QGIS update, my settings in the **Options panel** cannot be changed anymore.

Even before any Project is loaded, I have this error if I try to save in Options. Otherwise, I can work in QGIS with no apparent problems.

It seems there is a problem with my **User Defined CRS** and if I do not change it, nothing else in Options can be saved! I have to fix this first.

**The CRS definition format** is a Project string (Legacy - which it does not Recommend)  `+proj=lcc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-85 +lat_1=44.5 +lat_2=53.5 +x_0=930000 +y_0=6430000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs`

The other option is **WKT.** When I try to save it to that, it will not and I get this **error message** popup twice.

```
Cannot save ' * Generated CRS (+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +units=m +no_defs)'
— this Proj string definition is equivalent to ESRI:54004.
```

So I am stuck and unsure why or where to fix this CRS problem loop.

Does anyone have this happen or understand the issue?

Comment: Is it any custom CRS that can't be added or just the one that's equivalent to ESRI:54004?

Comment: I just tried to change to another CRS and I got this error  Cannot save ' * Generated CRS (+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +lat_ts=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +units=m +no_defs)' — this Proj string definition is equivalent to ESRI:54004.

Try changing the CRS definition to a WKT format instead.  (I did change it to a valid WKT format.)

Comment: May need to create a new profile

Comment: A new profile is pretty drastic. I would have to reset and link a lot of associated work settings. I still think my old custom CRS definitions need a tweak or to be deleted. BUT I am not sure what impact this might have on other projects. Needs investigating...

Comment: Success! I took the risk and deleted all my custom CRS definitions. Now I can save settings and move on... None were actually made by me, they were added perhaps as I was testing and converting other CRS maps. My thought is that if a custom def is needed to undo my deed, QGIS is "smart" enough to produce one again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete all the "* Generated CRS " from the User Defined CRS list. They have been not created by you, but they have been incorrectly created by an automated process e you very likely don't need them.